# How to instantiate final variables in Stateless Widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to assign certain values to some of the properties based on the input value. The value remains the same throughout the widget's life cycle. Therefore I used `Stateless` widget. But, I can't assign a value for the props from the constructor.

```
class InOrOut extends StatelessWidget {
  final Condition condition;
  final bool isIconVisible;
  final Color backgroudColor;
  final Color foregrounndColor;

  InOrOut({Key key, this.condition, this.isIconVisible}) : super(key: key) {
    switch (condition) {
      case Condition.IN:
        backgroudColor = Colors.green[100];
        foregrounndColor = Colors.green[100];
        isIconVisible = false
        break;
      case Condition.ABSENT:
        backgroudColor = Colors.grey[300];
        foregrounndColor = Colors.green[100];
        isIconVisible = true;
        break;
      case Condition.OUT:
        backgroudColor = Colors.red[100];
        foregrounndColor = Colors.green[100];
        isIconVisible = false;
        break;
      default:
        backgroudColor = Colors.red[100];
        foregrounndColor = Colors.green[100];
        isIconVisible = false;
    }
  }
```

The following error comes when trying to assign a value to prop:

> 'foregrounndColor' can't be used as a setter because it is final.
>   Try finding a different setter, or making 'foregrounndColor' non-final.dart(assignment_to_final)

If I remove `final` I can't use it inside the `Stateless` widget.

Finally, should I change to `Stateful` widget just because of this?

Comment: To keep it Stateless, you can just declare the properties as `late final`. An example in the answer below. dart@2.14.2

Comment: For those who are looking up this answer, this approach was wrong. In the above example, the variables could have been declared in the build method rather than calling them as final.

Comment: If you put them in the build method, those variables will be recalculated unnecessarily when the widget rebuilds. If it's a short calculation (like in your example), it's fine. But those variables in your example depend directly on the widget's input (`Condition`), which is final, so I still consider the approach of declaring them as `late` and initializing them in the constructor is acceptable. Why do you believe it's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your input @maganap. I didn't say using late is wrong. What I mean is that using Stateless widgets like this is senseless and they have the Stateful widgets exactly for this. I was under the impression that Stateful widget was bad for performance and should be avoided! Here I could have used a Stateful widget with the logic in the initState.

Comment: That in your example is not the reason of existence of Stateful widgets, I must say. I don't mean using a Stateful widget would be wrong, but it's certainly less efficient, and definitively unnecessary if your variables are `final`. If with little effort you can avoid unnecessary Stateful widgets, unnecessary rebuilds, and many other unnecessary "small" things like this, on the long term it will help keep performance issues away. So, if you can keep it Stateless, why not? A matter of trying to follow best practices, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To keep the widget Stateless, you need to declare the properties as `late final` and initialize them in the constructor. Example:

```dart
class IntroPage extends StatelessWidget {
  IntroPage(
    this.step, {
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key) {
    iconData = _getIconData(step);
    title = 'This is title ${step.toString()}';
    body = _getBody(step);
  }

  final IntroStep step;
  late final IconData iconData;
  late final String title;
  late final String body;

  IconData _getIconData(IntroStep step) {
    IconData iconData;
    switch (step) {
      case IntroStep.step1:
        iconData = Icons.share_sharp;
        break;
      case IntroStep.step2:
        iconData = Icons.sailing;
        break;
      case IntroStep.step3:
        iconData = Icons.grid_view_outlined;
        break;
    }
    return iconData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class InOrOut extends StatelessWidget {
  final Condition condition;
  final bool isIconVisible;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color foregroundColor;

  InOrOut({Key key, this.condition, bool isIconVisible})
      : backgroundColor = condition == Condition.IN
            ? Colors.green[100]
            : condition == Condition.ABSENT ? Colors.grey[300] : condition == Condition.OUT ? Colors.red[100] : Colors.red[100],
        foregroundColor = condition == Condition.IN
            ? Colors.green[100]
            : condition == Condition.ABSENT ? Colors.green[100] : condition == Condition.OUT ? Colors.green[100] : Colors.green[100],
        isIconVisible = condition == Condition.ABSENT,
        super(key: key);
}
```

so as I don't see the situation in general I'd prefer to have 3-4 separate widgets or use ternary operations inside build() method but obviously not a statefull widget

Comment: Thank you! Still, I hope there is a better way to do it. I think this could get more complicated with large no:of ternary conditions needed for the rest of the params that I need.

Comment: @Anoop.P.A so did you read https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const? and next time follow good advices ok?